# v-data-table ignores template when updating from Vuetify 1.5 => 2

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I had a working v-data-table, and was able to customize the displayed rows with a template. That code no longer works once updating to vuetify 2.0 (codepen link below). I'm assuming something has changed with vuetify, but I'm not sure what.

[Example](https://codepen.io/hurleyrc89/pen/KKPWWpQ)

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    class="elevation-1">
  <template v-slot:items="props">
    <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

In the example provided, I would only expect the first two columns to show (as it did in v1.5), however the default v-data-table view with all columns is still showing. Please help!

Comment: Hi, I assume they are all showing because you set them in the "headers" variable? In fact, unless you have more customization per row than your example above, you can pretty much ditch the whole template tag and deal only with the headers variable where you can even set the alignment. Like this: { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories', align: 'end' }, for example.

Comment: Unfortunately I do require more customization. I want to be able to add buttons, format speficific rows with {{ func(props.item.calories) }} etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        :search="search"
        show-group-by
    >
        <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
            <v-icon
                small
                class="mr-2"
                color="blue"
                @click="edit(item)"
            >
                edit
            </v-icon>
            <v-icon
                small
                color="red"
                @click="delete(item.id)"
            >
                delete
            </v-icon>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

in your script

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            search: "",
            headers: [
                {
                    text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
                    align: 'left',
                    sortable: false,
                    value: 'name',
                },
                {text: 'Calories', value: 'calories'},
                {text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat'},
                {text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs'},
                {text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein'},
                {text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron'},
                {text: 'Action', value: 'action'},
            ],
            desserts: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
                    calories: 159,
                    fat: 6.0,
                    carbs: 24,
                    protein: 4.0,
                    iron: '1%',
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
                    calories: 159,
                    fat: 6.0,
                    carbs: 24,
                    protein: 4.0,
                    iron: '1%',
                },

            ],
        };
    }, methods: {
        edit(id) {

        },
        delete(id) {

        },
    },
};
```

Comment: I'm more interested in customizing further. I want to be able to add buttons, format speficific rows with {{ func(props.item.calories) }} etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this asap

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. thanks! accepted as answer

Answer (score 3):

In vuetify v2, the items slot has been renamed, so for minimum changes, you just need to modify `items` to `item` in your original code.

```
<template v-slot:item="props">
```

[vuetify v2 release notes](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.0.0#user-content-upgrade-guide)

Comment: This answer just saved me and let me just add, prior to V2, I've only been using <td> inside <template>. Now, I need <tr> first then <td> inside. Otherwise, I can't have multiple rows in my table, and it stretches the data beyond the table view which is ugly.